# NRPE daemon turns ::1 into 52.0.0.0/14 subnet

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I configured NRPE daemon (`/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg`) in debug mode because of some startup problems and I realized that the `::1` found by default in the `allowed_hosts` directive:

```
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,::1,10.252.1.134
```

is magically turned into `52.0.0.0/14` according to the log:

```
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]: Warning: Cannot open log file '/usr/local/nagios/var/nrpe.log' for writing
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]: parse_allowed_hosts: parsing the allowed host string >127.0.0.1,::1,10.252.1.134< to add to ACL list
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]: add_ipv4_to_acl: checking ip-address >127.0.0.1<
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]: add_ipv4_to_acl: ip-address >127.0.0.1< correct, adding.
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]: add_ipv4_to_acl: checking ip-address >10.252.1.134<
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]: add_ipv4_to_acl: ip-address >10.252.1.134< correct, adding.
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]: Showing ACL lists for both IP and DOMAIN acl's:
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]:    IP ACL: 127.0.0.1/32 16777343
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]:    IP ACL: 52.0.0.0/14 52
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]:    IP ACL: 10.252.1.134/32 4269145354
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]: INFO: SSL/TLS initialized. All network traffic will be encrypted.
Sep  6 08:56:44 myhost nrpe[30830]: Starting up daemon
```

Is there any explanation for that?

NRPE version is **3.2.0**

Comment: The log seems to suggest that it ignores (doesn't process) `::1`, so most likely this version doesn't support IPv6. Also, `52.0.0.0/14` appears to be an Amazon address, so a speculative guess is that it's obtaining this from something relating to the host it's running on (network interface?), but I have no idea why it would be doing so.

Comment: does the host have an ipv6 loopback interface? and is it up? e.g., can you ping it?

Comment: @Keith, Yes. The hosts have a IPv6 loopback interface and it is up. It is *ping*able.

Answer (score 2):

After a quick glance on the source code (**acl.c**) I have found two issues:

1. Unlike `add_ipv4_to_acl` function, the `add_ipv6_to_acl` hardly shows a message in debug mode because of lack of calls to `logit()` function. The `add_ipv6_to_acl` function has no `logit()` call when the  IPv6 address is accepted, similar to this:

   ```
   if(debug == TRUE)
     logit(LOG_INFO, "add_ipv4_to_acl: ip-address >%s< correct, adding.", ipv4);
   ```

   **notice**: these lines shown are the last in the `add_ipv4_to_acl` function.

   That is why there is no line reporting `>::1< correct, adding.` in the log in debug mode.
2. The function `show_acl_lists()`, which displays the IP adress list, uses the `inet_ntoa()` call. But, according to the [manual pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa), **this function deals with IPv4 addresses, not with IPv6 ones**:

   ```
   while (ip_acl_curr != NULL) {
           logit(LOG_INFO, "   IP ACL: %s/%u %u\n", inet_ntoa(ip_acl_curr->addr),
                    prefix_from_mask(ip_acl_curr->mask), ip_acl_curr->addr.s_addr);
           ip_acl_curr = ip_acl_curr->next;
   }
   ```

Therefore I guess the problem here is that the `52.0.0.0/14` is the output of the `inet_ntoa()` function when a IPv6 address structure is used instead of a IPv4 address structure.

Yet I still have not compared both structures.

**update 1**

After installing NRPE in other node and having 4 IP addressed in the `allowed_hosts` directive, the ACL list entry shown for `::1` is different -- now it is `0.0.0.0/20`:

```
Showing ACL lists for both IP and DOMAIN acl's:
IP ACL: 127.0.0.1/32 16777343
IP ACL: 0.0.0.0/20 0
IP ACL: 10.252.1.134/32 4269145354
IP ACL: 10.252.1.135/32 896662794
```